# Adding an attribute to a css class with MooTools

Tags: mootools

I'd like to add an attribute to a CSS class using MooTools. I know that I can use removeClass and addClass to add and remove classes from different elements, but I'm looking to modify the global behavior of the entire class itself.

The only thing I can think of is doing $$('.classname').each and using set('style','whatever'). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

yes - there is a better way, you can redefine the CSS style itself, else you'd have to continuously apply changes every time you create a new element of that class and that's not very performant and practical.

check this answer: [Changing style of :hover selector in mootools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864599/changing-style-of-hover-selector-in-mootools) and the jsfiddle i made for it: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/Z9RPP/

Comment: oh yea Dimitar, +1, I thought 'a better way' in the sense of 'code syntax' :)

Comment: Very interesting approach. I wish there was a magic way to do it that didn't write a new <style> element, but I guess I do need to work in reality!
Thanks! :D